# Flask posting a Json file name and returning a Json file

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, flash

This is probably a basic question but somehow I could not yet find an complete answer to this. Basically, I have a Flask backend that has access to a folder with some Json files. I created a dropdown menu where all these json files are listed, and when I select one I would want for the Json content of that file to be passed to a JSON function.

Below is my Flask code

```py
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    json_files = [file for file in os.listdir("../../../../output") if file.endswith(".json")]
    return render_template("main.html", files=json_files)


@app.route('/get_game_file', methods=["POST"])
def get_game_file():
    file_name = Request().get_data()
    return json.load(f"../../../../output/{file_name}")
```

and below the javascript (with jquery)

```js
function getFile(fileName) {
    $.post("/get_game_file", fileName, function(gameJson) {console.log(gameJson)})
}
```

Basically, I was expecting that when I put console.log(gameJson) that the contents of the JSON file would be printed in the console. This is not the case though, as only the file name string is printed.

What is wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you attempted to load the JSON and store the valid JSON object in a variable then sending that valid JSON object back to the client? It looks like you're simply sending the file in this scenario and not the JSON object in it of itself.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do when I return the json file with the line return json.load(f"../../../../output/{file_name}"). But I do not fully understand achieve this